# How to reduce the android app bundle size in EAS EXPO?

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I created an empty project and uploaded it using EAS build for android. "eas build -p android". but the app.aab file has 30.9MB. An empty native project in kotlin/java has something about 5-7MB. How can I reduce this EAS app bundle?

[image: App bundle generated in eas]

Answer (score 0):

expo build:android -t app-bundle works for me

Comment: This is the command I used to get the 30.9MB app size, this didn`t work for me.